# Making posts more readable

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

As posts edits have to have more than 6 non-space edits, I wanted to ask what is the recommended way of improving posts that just need a couple of line breaks, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151078/about-java-cassandra-client-who-is-betterhow-about-cql/6180416#6180416). Flagging it, writing a comment? Both? Should I ignore it while reviewing? Maybe a new flag style and have a review-style role that allows some users to only edit style?

Comment: For your given example, you could capitalize API in the various places it shows up in lower case. As a cursory glance shows that there's indeed at least 3 different instances of `api`, you can easily reach your six characters without making the post confuse things with bees.

Comment: ok, did that. I could always just capitalize a couple of words to make the edit, but should i be worrying about this at all?

Comment: See my "improvements" to your suggested edit.

Comment: Don't capitalize as an excuse - capitalize because the post needs it. Stick to that thought pattern and only do what is a necessary capitalization (as well as any other related minor changes in high quantity), and you'll be green. Then you can see how others improve on that edit to see what you should look out for next. Always seek to tune your revisions to be even better. At a certain point, that 6 character limit really feels like nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have the requisite 2,000 rep for full edit privileges, and if you can't find 6 non-space edits, then just skip it.  It is not worth flagging for attention; if it truly is a problem, someone else with the necessary privileges will see it and fix it themselves.

However, if you do see capitalization, spelling, and/or spacing, issues that account for more then 6 characters, then go ahead and make the fix.